# How can call the backend Api through Alamofire swift Ios

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I've backend Api where I fetched the data through url session.Url session is quite complex for me as a beginner and data is not decoded properly through url session now some one suggest me to use Alamofier. Have read the documentation of alamofier but still confusing how i can fetch the all data and show in viewController.Please check my code of url session and guide me to convert into alamofier method thanks.

Networking Class:

```
struct NetworkService{
    static let  shared = NetworkService()
    private init(){
    }
    
    func fetchAllCategories(completion: @escaping(Result<AllDishes,Error>)-> Void){
        request(route: .fetchAllCategories, method: .get, completion: completion)
    }
    
    private func createRequest(route: Route, method: Method, parameters : [String:Any]? = nil) -> URLRequest?
    {
       
        let urlString1 = Route.baseUrl + route.description
        guard let  url = URL(string: urlString1) else { return nil }
        var urlRequest =  URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        if let params = parameters{
            switch method{
            case .get:
                var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: urlString1)
                urlComponent?.queryItems = params.map {
                    URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: "\($1)")}
                    urlRequest.url = urlComponent?.url
            case .post, .delete, .patch:
                let bodyData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
                urlRequest.httpBody = bodyData
            }
        }
        return urlRequest
    }
    private func request<T:Decodable>(route: Route,method: Method, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil, completion: @escaping(Result<T, Error>) -> Void){
        
        guard let request = createRequest(route: route, method: method, parameters: parameters) else {
            completion(.failure(AppError.unknownError))
            return
            
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
            var result: Result<Data, Error>?
            if let getData = data{
                result = .success(getData)
                let respondString = String(data:getData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "could not convert our data into string"
               print("backend response is \(respondString)")
            }
            else if let error = error{
                result = .failure(error)
                print("error is:\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("success \(result)")
                self.handleRequest(result: result , completion: completion)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    private func handleRequest<T:Decodable>(result:Result<Data, Error>?, completion: @escaping(Result<T, Error>) -> Void){
        guard let result = result else {
            completion(.failure(AppError.unknownError))
            return
        }
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let response = try? decoder.decode(ApiResponse<T>.self, from: data) else {
                completion(.failure(AppError.errorDecoding))
                return
            }
            if let error = response.error{
                completion(.failure(AppError.ServerError(error)))
            }
            if let decodedData = response.data{
                completion(.success(decodedData))
                
            }else{
                completion(.failure(AppError.unknownError))
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
      
    }
    
}
```

API Response Class:

```
struct ApiResponse <T:Decodable>: Decodable {
    let status: Int
    let message: String?
    let data: T?
    let error: String? 
    
}
```

AppError Class:

```
enum AppError: LocalizedError{
    case errorDecoding
    case unknownError
    case inValidUrl
    case ServerError(String)
    
    var errorDescription: String?{
        switch self{
        
        case .errorDecoding:
            return "response could not be decoded"
        case .unknownError:
            return "i have no idea what the error is"
        case .inValidUrl:
            return "give me a valid url"
        case .ServerError(let error):
            return error
        }
    }
}
```

Method Class:

```
enum Method: String{
    case get = "GET"
    case post = "POST"
    case delete = "DELETE"
    case patch = "PATCH"
}
```

Rout Class is that that return all the categories data and return.

```
enum Route{
    static let baseUrl = "https://yummie.glitch.me"
    case fetchAllCategories
    var description: String{
        switch self{
        case .fetchAllCategories:
            return "/dish-categories"
        }
    }
}
```

Home Controller Class:

```
var categoresdish: [DishCategory] = []{
        didSet{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    var popular: [Dish] = []{
        didSet{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    var specials: [Dish] = []{
        didSet{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
   
    private func loadData(){
        //ProgressHUD.show()
        NetworkService.shared.fetchAllCategories { [weak self] (result) in
            switch result{
               
            case .success(let allDishes):
               // ProgressHUD.dismiss()
                print("faheem ios success")
                self?.categoresdish = allDishes.categories ?? []
                self?.popular = allDishes.populars ?? []
                self?.specials = allDishes.specials ?? []
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("faheem error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
                ProgressHUD.showError()
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadData()
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @koen in handleReqeust function in a switch statement when i trying to decode the data data is not decoding even I get the data perfectly so can you help me see all the code and guide me how i can convert this code into alamofire pattern it's quite easy and efficient.